# Validating multiple fields on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to make it so that if the first field is has data the next 2 are required to have data also. Is there an easy way to do this for all rows?, each field has a unique id for the row do they all have to be unique?

[image: Fields]

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals There's no need to downvote the question. He didn't ask for the code solution for he's problem, you can just write a solution and let people figure out the code that works for them

Comment: Put a class on the first column, so you can easily find them. Do a `.each` for them, and if non-empty, check (assuming a table is used and the input is directly in a td) `$(this).parent().next().find('input')` and `$(this).parent().next().next().find('input')` to find the corresponding inputs.

Comment: I have tried plugins for contact 7 so far not actual code. I am a begginer and going through course academy so bear with me.

Comment: @JSantos I did not downvote the question :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, JSantos and ickmund.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals sorry then. I tough it was you. My fault for being hasty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".class-for-trade-in").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        var input_2 = $(this).parents("td").next().find("input");
        var input_3 = $(this).parents("td").next().next().find("input");
        // Validate the two inputs
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the fields must have unique ids. BUT... you can use classes instead of ids. Just use the same class for every element in the column. Then you can do a validation with jquery based on class name of the elements inside a specific row. If you paste some of your code on jsfiddle or similar service we can help you with the coding